# looping through collection of javascript objects

Tags: javascript

Am trying to read only very first element of friends array and add it to matches array for each object. If I add matches property directly on object. Then it returns expected result. But if I use a function addmatches to add matches array property. Then matches array value is coming same for each animal object.

```
var AnimalCreator = function(username, species, tagline, noises) {
  var friends = [];
   //var matches = [];
  return {
    username: username,
    species: species,
    tagline: tagline,
    noises: noises,
    friends: friends,
    //matches: matches
  }
};

var sheep = AnimalCreator('Cloud', 'sheep', 'You can count on me!', ['baahhh', 'arrgg', 'chewchewchew']);
var rabbit = AnimalCreator('Sky', 'Rabbit', 'I like jumping!', ['haha', 'heehee']);
var tiger = AnimalCreator('Tim', 'Tiger', 'I am strong!', ['Grrrr', 'grrrrrr!']);
var bear = AnimalCreator('Poo', 'Bear', 'I am your friend', ['wowo', 'whwhwh']);

var addFriend = function(animal, friend) {
  animal.friends.push(friend.username);
};

addFriend(sheep, rabbit);
addFriend(sheep, tiger);
addFriend(tiger, bear);

var myFarm = [sheep, rabbit, tiger, bear];

var addmatches  = function(farm){
  var matches = [];
  for(var i=0;i < farm.length; i++){
    farm[i].matches = matches;
  }
};

addmatches(myFarm);
var giveMatches = function(farm) {
  for (var i = 0; i < farm.length; i++) {
    if (farm[i].friends.length > 0) {
      farm[i].matches.push(farm[i].friends[0]);
    }
  }
};
giveMatches(myFarm);
console.log(myFarm);
```

Comment: Well, what is your `addMatches` function supposed to do? As of right now, assigning the same `matches` array to every animal is exactly what it does, and that's all it does.

Comment: addMatches function is adding 'matches' property to the object.

Comment: if I add matches propperty directly on object by uncommenting matches property in AnimalCreator function. And commenting out addmatches function.
Notice matches array for each object . Why it's giving different values for matches property in these 2 scenarios

Answer (score 2):

`matches` is a reference to an empty array and your code is assigning same reference for every `farm` object ( `farm[i].matches = matches;` ), you can try by assigning empty array directly like

```
farm[i].matches = [];
```

**Your commented code:** The function `AnimalCreator` is creating a new array instance on every call and every `animal` object is referencing to a unique array, that's why when you directly add `matches`, it works as expected.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 2):

This is because array is passed by referance, so every farm object is pointing to the same array by this "farm[i].matches = matches;". To fix this you can do multiple tihings.

1. Change "farm[i].matches = matches;" to "farm[i].matches = [];" (Best option as of now).
2. Move "var matches = [];" inside for loop and use "let" insted of "var".